# Creating an Event for Textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-store-apps, textblock

I am trying to create a TextChanged Event Handler for a TextBlock using Custom Dependency Property in WindowsstoreApp(WPF),The Event is not getting fired,I dont know where I went wrong,Please guide me ,I have tried so far is,

```
 public sealed partial class BuyerInput : Page
{       

    public BuyerInput()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyTextblock.SetBinding(MyTextProperty, new Binding { Source = MyTextblock.Text,Path = new PropertyPath("MyText") });
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =   DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(BuyerInput), typeof(string), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnMyTextChanged));

    public static void OnMyTextChanged(DependencyObject d,  DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this event is not getting fired whenever the value is changed in TextBlock(MyTextblock)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **DP registration is incorrect**. It should be like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(BuyerInput),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
           {
              BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
              DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
              PropertyChangedCallback = OnMyTextChanged
           });

public string MyText
{
   get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
   set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnMyTextChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
}
```

**Explanation**:

- OwneType and DP type parameters are swapped in your registration.
- DP wrappers are missing.
- And make DP to bind `TwoWay`. Default is `OneWay`.

---

Binding also is not correct. In case you want to bind to TextBlock name MyTextBlock, it should be:

```
MyTextblock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty,
      new Binding { Source = this,Path = new PropertyPath("MyText"), 
                    Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay });
```

---

**Update** for comment -

> I can't find FrameworkPropertyMetadata in WindowsStoreApp.

In case `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` is not available on WinRT, use your `PropertyMetadata`, that will work as well. But you need to set `Mode` to `TwoWay` on your binding. I have updated the binding above.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer,But I can't find FrameworkPropertyMetadata in WindowsStoreApp.

Comment: Oh so use your PropertyChangeCallback with other changes. That will work. You than have to set `Mode=TwoWay` on binding.

Comment: Could you please explain elaborately about PropertyChangeCallback?

Comment: Oh sorry i meant `PropertyMetadata` which your are using originally in your post. Use that only.